# 18.04 - how to create PID file in systemd unit?

Tags: server, java, systemd, minecraft, tmux

I am trying to properly setup my minecraft server with systemd so that it correctly determines the main PID for the process. I have the following systemd service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft

WorkingDirectory=/srv/minecraft

ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true

Type=forking

ExecStartPre=/srv/minecraft/mc_server.sh setup
ExecStart=/srv/minecraft/mc_server.sh start

PIDFile=/srv/minecraft/mc.pid

ExecStop=/srv/minecraft/mc_server.sh stop


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I attempt to start the service, I get this error message (the main issue being the "**failed to parse PID from file**" part):

```
minecraft.service - Minecraft Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minecraft.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2018-11-28 12:57:03 PST; 6min ago
  Process: 9611 ExecStart=/srv/minecraft/mc_server.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9591 ExecStartPre=/srv/minecraft/mc_server.sh setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5213 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx mc_server.sh[9591]: No Session found.  Creating and configuring.
Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Found left-over process 9607 (tmux: server) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx  systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx  systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Found left-over process 9608 (bash) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx  systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx  mc_server.sh[9611]: Minecraft server successfully started
Nov 28 12:55:32 xxx  systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Failed to parse PID from file /srv/minecraft/mc.pid: Invalid argument
Nov 28 12:57:02 xxx  systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Nov 28 12:57:03 xxx  systemd[1]: minecraft.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 28 12:57:03 xxx  systemd[1]: Failed to start Minecraft Server.
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. If I remove the PIDfile= option then it works, but lists the tmux process as the main PID and therefore doesn't record output from the java process in the logs. **I also just noticed that it's not actually writing the PID to mc.pid**. When running the script directly it does write the PID correctly.

Here is the contents of "mc_server.sh start", which is how I'm starting the server and creating the PID file (note that the tmux session is created during "mc_server.sh setup"):

```
/usr/bin/tmux send-keys -t minecraft '/usr/bin/java -server -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar /srv/minecraft/minecraft_server.jar nogui' C-m && \
/usr/bin/pgrep -u minecraft -f minecraft_server.jar > /srv/minecraft/mc.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

Option *PIDFile* of systemd is used to read PID, not create. It mentioned in [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PIDFile=)

> Takes a path referring to the PID file of the service. Usage of this option is recommended for services where Type= is set to forking. The path specified typically points to a file below /run/. If a relative path is specified it is hence prefixed with /run/. The service manager will read the PID of the main process of the service from this file after start-up of the service. The service manager will not write to the file configured here, although it will remove the file after the service has shut down if it still exists. The PID file does not need to be owned by a privileged user, but if it is owned by an unprivileged user additional safety restrictions are enforced: the file may not be a symlink to a file owned by a different user (neither directly nor indirectly), and the PID file must refer to a process already belonging to the service.
>
> Note that PID files should be avoided in modern projects. Use Type=notify or Type=simple where possible, which does not require use of PID files to determine the main process of a service and avoids needless forking.

Also great answer represented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724450/15915956

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).